# How can I send a silent notifications using app center push service

Tags: android, push-notification, visual-studio-app-center, silent-notification

I am trying to send a silent notification (I mean a notification that will not be shown in the tray) using
[this API](https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/push/Push_Send):

but when I do not set the body key I get this Error:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "body parameter is invalid or empty.: 'Body' cannot be null."
  }
}
```

so my question is if there is a way to send a silent notification in android (in ios I know there is the [content-available flag](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW8))

Tnx in advance!

Comment: use data node instead of notification node of body. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: I see Sarahm is using AppCenter API and not directly FCM. @killer, is this will work via the AppCenter API?

Comment: my bad I didn't understand the question clearly.

Comment: Is is possible to use Firebase API directly? I tried, but without any luck, seems that I have to set up firebase in app separately

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately silent notification is not yet supported on App Center for Android.

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume, you were 100% right. I just got the confirmation from your support (that was not aware of that limitation)

"Unfortunately, I just confirmed that it is currently unavailable for Android. Guillaume is indeed one of the engineers on our team and is a great source of information. I understand it is something we will be working on but no ETA at the moment."

Comment: @Guillaume thank you for the information! 
Is there any update about ETA for silent notification support on App Center? Are there any workaround at the moment?

Comment: Any eta ? This seems an important feature.

Comment: Hi, for feature requests I would recommend contacting the team on the chat support from any page of https://appcenter.ms.

Comment: Can you add this somewhere in the docs? I went through the whole SDK setup process and now I have to use to Firebase anyways...

Answer (score 4):

I've asked AppCenter support via their live chat and they replied me the following

> You can by setting “content-available”  key in the custom data. here is a sample payload you need to set in body:

```
“notification_content” : {  
   “name” : “name of Push”,  
   “custom_data” : {“content-available” : “1”}  
},
```

Comment: I've asked if this is documented and they replied that their documentation is not yet complet

Comment: I tried it for Android, but it's not working - my app still displays notification in tray.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed,

> “notification_content” : {
>     “name” : “name of Push”,
>     “custom_data” : {“content-available” : “1”}
>   },

is for silent push notifications in ios

Comment: is there any additional set up to handle silent push messages? I tried to send message as you described, but my callback is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Android and iOS

```
{
  "notification_target": {
    "type": "devices_target",
    "devices": [
      "43533adc-4133-4121-ad4e-1eb4885b4b98"
    ]
  },
  "notification_content": {
    "name": "edd3-43ef-91f5-276c28a86517",
    "title": "",
    "body": "",
    "custom_data": {
      "content-available": "1",
      "id": "your data"
    }
  }
}
```